# Validation in shared folder in GWT app

Tags: java, gwt

I am new to GWT and I am doing the validations,to avoid duplicate insertion of the patient into data base,I created a class on the shared side and loaded all users from the data base into a list and compared it with the new user data.

**On Shared Side:**

```
package de.chieukam.tutorial.shared;


import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import de.chieukam.tutorial.server.PatientDAO;

public class PatientCreationValidation {

    private PatientDAO patientDAO;
    private boolean duplicate;

    public PatientCreationValidation(){

        this.patientDAO=new PatientDAO();
        this.duplicate=false;
    }


    public boolean checkDuplicatePatient(String name,String FirstName,Date date){

        List<PatientDTO> findAll=patientDAO.findAll();

        for(PatientDTO npatient:findAll){

            if(npatient.getLastName().equals(name)){

                duplicate=true;
                break;
            }


        }

        return duplicate;


    }
```

**on client Side:**

```
duplicatePatient= patientValidation.checkDuplicatePatient(textName.getText(), textFirstName.getText(), boxBirthday.getValue());

        if(duplicatePatient){
            GwtSpringHibernate.showAlertBox(" Patient Already Exists ");

            return;
        }
```

it gives the error

```
[ERROR] [GwtSpringHibernate] - Line 12: No source code is available for type de.chieukam.tutorial.server.PatientDAO; did you forget to inherit a required module?

[ERROR] [GwtSpringHibernate] - Unable to find type 'de.chieukam.tutorial.client.widgets.NewPatientDialog.AddiSelectWidgetUiBinder'

[ERROR] [GwtSpringHibernate] - Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly

[ERROR] [GwtSpringHibernate] - Deferred binding failed for 'de.chieukam.tutorial.client.widgets.NewPatientDialog.AddiSelectWidgetUiBinder'; expect subsequent failures.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use server side classes inside shared classes

```
de.chieukam.tutorial.server.PatientDAO
```

above line is in the problem at shared side.

Read here about [GWT MVP atchitecture](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html)

Read more here about [GWT Architectural Perspectives](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.doc.DeveloperGuide.RemoteProcedureCalls.ArchitecturalPerspectives.html)

Read below comments for more information.

Comment: Can I assume `shared` section as `client` and what are different between **shared** and **client** packages ?

Comment: shared packages are used for utilities and POJO classes that is used as DTO between server and client. shared packages are converted into JavaScript while GWT compilation.

Comment: What have you mentioned in gwt.xml? client packages is purely for UI generation. If you include `<source path='shared' />` in your gwt.xml that shared classes are also included in compiled JavaScript.

Comment: I would like to know about **utilities** , I don't know exactly what is **utilities** ? I write POJOs , validators , customize widgets , customize dialogs classes under the **shared** package. Do you mean these are **utilities** ? Has another ? Greatly thanks to you :)

Comment: Do not use any GWT UI specific code in shared classes. shared packages are also visible to server and there is no meaning of your customized widgets. Utilities means some validation checks, some conversion classes.

Comment: Here shared means classes that are shared between client and server. It doesn't mean you place some reusable GWT UI components into it. You can create an another package such as `com.x.y.z.client.shared` if you need.